# Android - Testing a simple Activity method

Tags: android, exception, testing, android-activity

i'm writing you today because i have a real and concrete question about how testing an activity method. Let me explain the situation.

I have an activity (A) which use a method save(param) from a service (S). This method throws a specific exception if the parameter is invalid.

Unit tests are written for this part, and now, i would like to test the Activity part :

In my Activty, i use the following code to call the save() method

```
public void OnSaveClicked()
{
    try{
        if ( S.save(my_object) > 0 ) // Object Saved
        {
          ShowToast(this, "Your object has been saved successfully !");
        }
        else { // Error occured with the database
          ShowToast(this, "An error occured with the database");
        }
     catch (MyException ex)
     {
         ShowToast(this, "The object you are trying to save is not valid... Please check information you entered");
     }
}
```

The test that i'm trying to write has to check if the save() method raised the exception or not. To do that, i simulate a click on the UI Button, but, **i don't really know what do i have to check**. I read that's not possible to write an assert on a toast message. I'm currently thinking about using a dialog but i am not sure that the way i'm thinking is the right one. Is it normal to test that or not ?

Would you give me your feedback about that, and discuss about the right way to test activity ?

Thanks,

t00f

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Robolectric. They have support for assertions like this http://groups.google.com/group/robolectric/browse_thread/thread/87952e620ce1bb37?pli=1

Thanks,

Ian